# Microsoft Access database connection path for Class and Jar

Tags: netbeans

I had been searching hi & lo for this in this forum and googling around. I am still stuck with this. I m new to Netbeans/Java. Here is what I want to do and trying for the pass few days.

I had a folder named as resources and the path is like this src/resources, in the "resources"
folder, there is a MS Access Database file: Database1.mdb.

If I use the full path:
Example:

```
C:\Users\Mr A B\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Report\src\report\resources\Database1.mdb

java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:\\Users\\Mr A B\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Report\\src\\report\\resources\\Database1.mdb
```

I'm able to Test and run. But When run from the "Dist" folder containing the cleaned and built jar file, `Exception "Data Source Name not found and No Default Driver Specified"`

I tried with

`getClass().getResource("resources/Database1.mdb")`

and

`URL url=Connection.class.getResource(resources/Database1.mdb");`

It is easy to do it in C#/VB.net by just supplying the App.path..

I m running out of idea.

Pls help

thnks